# write file to txt in python gives typerror

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
with open('logAq.txt', 'w') as fw:
    a=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\dddd.txt", sep=",")                   
    b=a[['dates','user']]
    b.groupby(['dates','user'])['dates'].count().sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[False,True])

    final=b.sort_values(['dates'],ascending=False).groupby(['dates','user'], sort=False)['dates'].count()
    fw.write(final)
```

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Series

What should be done for the result of the `final` to be written in a txt?

Comment: what is the input and expected output?

Comment: You could try: `fw.write(str(final))` or use pickle and store the series as binary.

Comment: the input is a csv and the output is a group by that gives the users according to a certain date.

Comment: @meissner_ Worked perfectly

Comment: Why not use the [Pandas support for writing dataframes and series to files](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-out-data)?

Comment: Or were you trying to write a single value? What should `final` *be*, `.count()` produces a series of counts. As Nihal states, please share the *expected* result, clearly.

Comment: What exactly the final returns but in a txt.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable `final` is list, then you have to just loop over the values and write value to the output.

```
for value in final:
    fw.write(value+'\n')
```

Or something similar...

Comment: It's not a list, it's a Pandas Series, the error is clear it's not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding str(final) before fw.write(final)